# VBA - syntax for .pictures.insert incorrect? Insert method of picture class failed

Tags: vba

I am new to VBA and am trying to make a macro that uses cell contents as the name of the picture file to insert. I keep getting 1004 error: Insert method of picture class failed. How do I fix this?

```
Sub simplepic()
'
' simplepic Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+l
'
    ActiveCell.Select
    Dim picname As String
    picname = Range(ActiveCell)
    ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=-1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert ( _
        "C:\Users\Briet\Documents\PAJ\pic-presentation\Images\" & picname & ".jpg")
End Sub
```

Comment: leave off the parentheses since you are not making a function call (not expecting a return value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need:

```
ActiveCell.Select
Dim picname As String
picname = Range(ActiveCell)
```

It seems that you want

```
Dim picname As String
picname = ActiveCell.Value
```

- No need to select the active cell (it's active, i.e. it is selected)
- you don't want to reference a range based on the value of the active cell, do you? You presumably want the value of the cell

Next problem might be the way you select "the cell above this one". I found the following code worked fine (no errors):

```
ActiveCell.Select
Dim picname As String
picname = ActiveCell.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert "C:\myPath\myPicture.png"
```

See if that works for you (with an appropriate path), then add things back in until it fails and let us know if you still can't figure it out.